# Clone git repo to Google Drive

Tags: git

I've seen on SO and elsewhere that having a Git Repo on Google Drive is not recommended. However, can I clone a Git repo (hosted on GitHub or Bitbucket) to Google Drive or will it have the same issue?

My scenario is related to using multiple computers. Say I have checked out a repo to Computer 1 at work and working on feature A but before I finish feature A, I need to leave work. Now, I don't want to push my changes to the remote repo as it is not finished but I want to work on it on Computer 2 (at home). If the clone is in Google Drive, I can pick up where I left off and push when Feature A is complete.

Or does a clone on Google Drive have the same issues as a repo on Google Drive?

Edit: I should have said, the other thing I like about having the clone in Google Drive is that I only have one working clone so I do not need to worry about pushing and pulling when switching between computers.

Comment: The [Version Control Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) were invented (40+ years ago) to solve the problem you have today, working on multiple computers (by different persons or the same person, it doesn't really matter). What you ask now is if it's better to ignore all the features a VCS offers and handle everything manually (like it was before VCSes). A branch is all you need and Git excels on handling them. Read about [Git branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).

Comment: It will have the same issues. **Do not** mix file/folder synchronization mechanisms and DVCS repositories.

Comment: The solution to your question is just to use branches. Create a branch for your work that you push to, this doesn't have to be done, doesn't have to build, doesn't even have to be complete code. Simply do a `git commit --amend` if you want to "continue" on the last commit when you get home. Since this is *your* branch, nobody else should care if you replace a commit on it with an updated commit from that other computer.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I need to do some further reading. @Lasse - do I not need to push rather than commit to be able to carry on from home? (i.e. the commit will only be on my local copy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> Now, I don't want to push my changes to the remote repo as it is not finished but I want to work on it on Computer 2 (at home).

There are a number of solutions to this problem which do not involve something as exotic as using Google Drive as a Git repo.

One option would be to simply commit and push your unfinished work to your regular Git repository (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket).  Then, pull that branch at home, complete the feature, and amend the HEAD commit:

```
git commit ---amend 'finished the feature at home'
git push --force origin yourBranch
```

Note that force pushing is necessary because we have rewritten the history of the branch.

But this option might not be so good if the branch in question is publicly shared.  In that case, your temporary commit could be buried by others' work.  A workaround for this would be to just create a second branch containing your unfinished work.  Then, pull this second branch at home, finish the work, and bring it into the main branch via a merge or rebase.

One of Git's strong points is its ability to function well in a distributed environment.  You should try to see what Git can already do for you out of the box.